# Errors in Routes requests

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

im working in a project using angularjs and laravel, but i have a bug i think in my application, im not sure since it happens sometimes, not always. Basically when i open or run my application are made some requests to some routes, but sometimes give me a 500 error, and than the error that is shown in the preview is:

```
RuntimeException in ApiServiceProvider.php line 88:
Unable to boot ApiServiceProvider, configure an API domain or prefix.
```

I searched online this error and didnt find much info related with this error, does someone have a idea what could it be?

Comment: This error message seems pretty clear at first glance. It's going to be tough for anyone to provide any concrete help without seeing your code. Forgive me for being captive obvious, but it appears your ApiServiceProvider is only getting configured properly some of the time. Go through your code and see if there are any "hooks" where it would be possible for your config to get unset or not set at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I have solved the problem, the thing is that you are missing configurations.

The way to solve it you have to make a copy of .env.example file and rename it to **.env**

Do not forget to change you database configurations.

The problem was missing domain or prefix. which is in your case is:
**API_PREFIX=api**

I`m sure that it should solve your problem.

Helpful hint turn on your debugging environment in config/app.php to 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true)

so you can be more specific with error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem even if API_PREFIX was set in my .env file. 
Simple solution that I found after long struggle was to clear cache:

```
php artisan chache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```